# Can we consider the Hamiltonian of a single qubit as zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

I am studying the Daniel Lidar`s lecture notes about open quantum systems. In the part that I have already attached it here, it considers the Hamiltonian of the single qubit as zero to implement into Lindblad equation. I am woundering what is the reason for this consideration?

Here it goes:
[image]

I will be so thankful if you can help me out in terms of this issue.

Normally we consider the Hamiltonian of a single qubit like this:

$$H = h_0 I +\sum_{i\in \{x,y,z\}} h_i \sigma^i$$

Comment: Maybe he is considering the example where all $h_\mu=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity the Hamiltonian can be zero, but I doubt that is the case here. What is probably happening here is that he is using the [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture).

The reason this is done is because to derive the Lindblad equation one particular approximation is desirable, know as the rotating wave approximation, but for that I think a reference is better than an explanation here because the derivation of a master equation is long and tedious. See [Breuer's book](https://academic.oup.com/book/27757) on open quantum systems on chapter 3.

If the Hamiltonian really is zero, the physical interpretation would simply be that both energy levels are degenerate.

Note that in the way you've written the Hamiltonian for qubit there is no problem in having all $h_i = 0$, therefore if $H =0 $ still has the form written (of course by $0$ I mean a matrix where all entries are zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Could you please show me and clarify how degenerate energy levels could entail 0 for the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Can we agree that the Hamiltonian has to be constant for it to be degenerate? If yes, then an overall constant doesn't change the dynamics of the system and can therefore be discarted. If you don't agree with my first point I can clarity more.

Comment: I have to give a big apology for taking your time but, could you please clarify more?

Comment: Any Hamiltonian for a qubit can be written as a 2x2 matrix, and it can also be diagonalized, therefore there is always a basis where the Hamiltonian can be written as ((v1, 0 ) , (0, v2)), where v1 and v2 are the eigenvalues. By definition, degenerate levels have the same energy (aka the same eigenvalues for H), therefore v1 = v2. Then there is the point that an identity has no physical impact on the system as it only adds a global phase to your state (and a global phase is not measurable). Does this clarify?

Comment: yes completely!